# Unable to start debugging on web server error remote server returned an error (500) Internal server error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-2019

I have developed a simple web application in Visual Studio 2019 in asp.net core to implement windows authentication. But while running the application in Local IIS it returns with error code 500 (Internal Server error). I have tried changing windows features and restarted IIS but it's not working.

[Visual Studio 2019 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK1FL.png)

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html Very likely you forgot ASP.NET Core module installation.

Comment: Have you installed both IIS->application development features->asp.net related feature and Visual studio Development time IIS support? You need to ensure both of them have been installed.  Otherwise, you could try to install .net core webhosting bundle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle.